How to increasing graphic card rendering speed?
please help me with my querry and help me answer this question my graphic card is Nvdia 840M i want to icrease its rendering speed is there anyway possible to make show that increase speed in Adobe premier.

Adobe Premiere rendering is heavy process. And laptop is not the right tool for this.

You will have to replace the hardware with a GPU with more capability

You need to replace the GPU with a faster one. There’s no magic wand waving to make yours faster.
Since your GeForce 840M indicates a laptop that likely means you need to replace the laptop. The 840M is ten years old, so might need replacement anyway.
